# Finding field size in byte for the fields Scapy support

Tags: python, size, field, byte, scapy

How can I find the size of a particular field that Scapy support. For example what  is the size of LongField (in bytes)? I checked the scapy documentation, but couldn't find it (http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/doc/build_dissect.html#fields) .
Is there any function to check it, or any documentation which shares this info.

Answer (score 3):

Just have a look at the source-code. Scapys built-int fields use `struct.pack()` to convert integers to various length Big- and Little-Endian representations. The [LongField](https://github.com/syakesaba/scapy/blob/master/scapy/fields.py#L326) which is an implementation of [Field](https://github.com/syakesaba/scapy/blob/master/scapy/fields.py#L22) in particular will serialize as `fmt=Q` which according to the python documentation for [struct](https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html) has a size of `Q unsigned long long  integer 8` (also see `struct.calcsize`)

Always note that Fields can be highly specific to one protocol. However, you could, for the fields based on `class Field` try to access the instances `fmt` attribute. However, this can be inaccurate as your field could have an overridden serialization method. A **more generic solution** would be to spawn an instance of the Field, serialize it and call `len()` on it.

(Note: links to an inofficial github mirror)