# Defining custom protocols in Scapy - field length

Tags: python, scapy

I've found previous stackoverflow questions that are relevant to my question but I don't believe I followed the suggestions. I want to define a 16 byte field and seeing references to how Scapy uses struct for sizing (https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html#format-characters) I don't quite follow how that maps back to the guidance found in the docs here (https://scapy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/build_dissect.html#fields). I'm missing the piece that allows me to connect these areas together so that not only can I create my 16 byte field I can understand how fields are defined in terms of size.

Threads referenced:
[Finding field size in byte for the fields Scapy support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33418855/finding-field-size-in-byte-for-the-fields-scapy-support)

[How to set byte size of my fields in a custom scapy class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72565640/how-to-set-byte-size-of-my-fields-in-a-custom-scapy-class)